# Can I run IOS apps on Android phone?

Tags: android, iphone

I want to run **IOS** apps on my **Android** phone. Is there any way to do so? If the answer is yes, can you provide me with the steps that I need to follow to download **Appstore** apps without having the **Appstore**?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]. SO is for _programming_ questions. For general hardware and software questions, try our network site [su].

Comment: I think it is a relevant programming question.

Comment: How is it a programming question, @gorn? OP asks how to _use_ iOS apps on their Android device. Nothing here is about programming.

Answer (score 2):

No, you simply can't. iOS apps rely on iOS operating system that facilitates execution of binary in [mach-o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) format by [XNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU) kernel and provides iOS-specific system frameworks and swift runtime. Nothing of this can be provided by Android operating system.

Comment: But is there any way to that like using any emulators can I run them on windows PC?

Comment: You can run VMWare macOS virtual machine on windows, and run emulator from the virtual machine

Comment: However, that’s against macOS terms and conditions, so I don’t recommend you doing so.

Answer (score 0):

No. iOS and iPadOS apps use either Objective-C or Swift, while Android ones generally tend to use Kotlin, Java, and C++. Let's also not forget that iPhone applications use APIs and frameworks that are only available on Apple operating systems.